# « Mettre la (les) main(s) à la pâte/dans le cambouis » : comparaisons ?

Tags: prépositions, étymologie, expressions-idiomatiques, locutions

*Mettre la main à la pâte*, c'est « entreprendre quelque chose, y prêter son concours, participer activement à un travail » ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/main/48688/locution)) ; on le note de registre familier pour « intervenir dans un travail, dans une entreprise » ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/main)). D'autre part on a entendu *mettre les mains dans le cambouis* pour « se confronter à un problème de manière pratique » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mettre_les_mains_dans_le_cambouis)) ; incidemment on ne connaît pas l'[origine](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/cambouis) du [*cambouis*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/47326).

---

- Les deux locutions se ressemblent (*mettre*, la *main*, la
  *matière*), et évoquent des réalités concrètes, matérielles ; en quoi diffèrent-elles précisément (sens, emplois etc.) ?
- En ce qui a trait au nombre, y a-t-il une raison pour laquelle on a une main au singulier dans la première et deux mains, au pluriel, dans la seconde ?
- Pourquoi ce dans quoi on met la main est-il introduit dans un cas avec
  la préposition *à* et dans l'autre avec *dans* ; est-ce que ça donne une idée du moment où s'est élaborée une locution, de la similarité/différence entre elles ?
- Incidemment, a-t-on de nouvelles informations au sujet de l'origine du *cambouis* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ces expressions ne sont pas totalement interchangeables, de par leurs connotations respectives, mais seulement très proches dans le sens.

"*Mettre les mains dans le cambouis*", au sens propre, c'est mettre les mains sous le capot d'une voiture pour réparer un moteur, d'où le sens de prêtre main forte, d'aider, de participer à une tâche, mais c'est aussi, comme le sens propre de l'expression nous le montre, se salir, se graisser copieusement les mains avec le cambouis du moteur, qui tache fortement, et qui n'est pas très très agréable. On doit "se mouiller" pour arriver à une résolution du problème, qui a l'air un peu casse-tête.

D'où la connotation de participer à une tâche difficile (qui "tache"), ou ingrate, ou qui demande beaucoup d'expertise et une plongée très au cœur du fonctionnement du système.

Ex:
Mon site internet est complètement à réécrire, je vais devoir mettre les mains dans le cambouis! Il faut que je relise tout le code, et que je corrige toutes les fonctions qui appellent de mauvais paramètres.

On comprend que ce n'est pas forcément de gaieté de cœur.

"*Mettre la main à la pâte*" a une connotation plus légère. Il s'agit ici au sens propre de "prêter" sa main pour fournir un travail (ici: pétrissage de la pâte).
Il y a la connotation d'aider à une tâche collective en fournissant sa force de travail.
Par exemple, une tâche déjà en cours.

Ex:
*En ce moment, on fait l'inventaire du magasin, tout le monde participe, je vais devoir mettre la main à la pâte.*

C'est le type d'utilisation le plus courant de cette expression il me semble.

S'il s'agit d'une tâche qui n'est pas en cours, ou commencée par d'autres personnes, et individuelle, on aura sans doute la connotation de "*s'y mettre*".

*Il faut que j'obtienne mon examen ! Je vais mettre la main à la pâte !*

On comprend ici que, dans cette phrase, on n'aurait pas du tout pu utiliser "*mettre les mains dans le cambouis*", sans que le sens soit totalement différent. Dit comme ça: "Il faut que j'obtienne mon examen, et mette les mains dans le cambouis", la phrase n'a pas vraiment de sens. On ne comprend pas ce que la personne doit analyser et réparer pour obtenir son examen.

Pour "cambouis", je pense que ça mériterait, à lui seul, d'ouvrir un autre sujet. L'explication est déjà très longue !

Pour le fait d'avoir "les mains" et "mettre la main", la première expression demandant plus d'efforts que la première, et il est difficile de réparer un moteur avec seulement une main, il faut y mettre les 2 et ne pas avoir peur de se salir. *La main à la pâte*, si on la voit comme une participation à une tâche c'est souligné par l'emploi d'une seule main. Mettre les 2 mains à la pâte traduirait un travail plus difficile si l'expression existait.

**NB** Il vaut mieux éviter d'utiliser le *wiktionnaire*, qui donne parfois des définitions farfelues, du sens que l'auteur de l'article *pense* que le mot a. *On n'y donne aucune source* pour justifier une définition. Ce n'est pas à proprement parler un *dictionnaire*, bien que certains articles soient intéressants, il faut s'en méfier et ne pas le prendre comme une référence, mais comme une aide.